# Non vanishing polynomial in the Poincaré upper-half plane

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, positive-definite

> Let $ A_{1}, \dots , A_{m} $ be real positive semidefinite matrices and consider the polynomial $$ p(z_{1}, \dots , z_{m})=\det(\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_{i}A_{i}) \in \mathbb{C}[z_{1}, \dots ,z_{m}] $$
>
> I am asked to show that:
>
> i) $ \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}A_{i} $ is positive definite for all $ c_{1}, \dots ,c_{m}>0 $ if and only if $ p $ is not the zero polynomial.
>
> ii)  if $ p $ is not the zero polynomial, then $ p(z_{1}, \dots , z_{m}) \neq 0 $ for all $ z_{1}, \dots ,z_{m} $ in the Poincare upper-half plane i.e. for all $z_{1}, \dots ,z_{m} $ with $ \mathcal{I}m(z_{i})>0 $ $ \forall i \in \overline{1,m} $.

I was able to prove the direct implication in i) since if $A(c_{1}, \dots ,c_{m})= \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}A_{i} $ is positive definite this means that all the eigenvalues of $ A(c_{1}, \dots, c_{m}) $ are strictly positive, hence their product is strictly positive so in particular non-zero. On the other hand, the product of the eigenvalues is equal tot the determinant of $ A(c_{1}, \dots c_{m}) $  which is in fact $ p(c_{1}, \dots ,c_{m}) $. Therefore $ p $ is non-zero.

I don't know though how to approach the converse.

For part ii) I did as follows:

Suppose that $ p $ is non-zero. Then by i), we have that  $ \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}A_{i} $ is positive definite for all $ c_{1}, \dots ,c_{m}>0 $ so in particular this holds true for the imaginary parts of the $ z_{i}$'s.

Write $ z_{j}=a_{j}+ib_{j} $ for all $ j \in \overline{1,m}  $. Then we have that $$ p(z_{1}, \dots , z_{m})=det(\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_{i}A_{i})=det\big(\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}A_{j}+i(\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A_{j})\big) $$
Call $$ A=\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{j}A_{j} $$ and $$ B=\sum_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A_{j} $$
Then we must show that $ det(A+iB) \neq 0 $. Since $ B $ is a positive definite matrix, it is invertible so multiplying by $ det(B^{-1}) $, we see that it suffices to show that $ det(B^{-1}A+iI) \neq 0 $ which is equivalent to showing that $$ det(I+i(-B^{-1}A)) \neq 0 $$

Now $ B $ is symmetric and invertible, hence its inverse is also symmetric. I know that the product of two symmetric matrices is symmetric iff the two matrices commute so it would suffice to show that $ A $ and $ B $ commute since this certainly implies that $ A $ and $ B^{-1} $ commute as well in order to get that $ -B^{-1}A $ is a real symmetric matrix which would clearly finish the proof.

The issue is that $ A $ and $ B $ don't seem to commute in general since for example if we take $ m=2 $, we should have that $$a_{1}b_{2}A_{1}A_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}A_{2}A_{1}=b_{2}a_{1}A_{2}A_{1}+b_{1}a_{2}A_{1}A_{2} $$ which can clearly be false for infinitely many choices of the $ a_{i}'s$ and $ b_{i}'s $.

Maybe there is a better way to approach this or maybe I am missing something.

I would really appreciate any help with both the last question as well as the converse implication from i). Thank you in advance!